# Nominatim's OpenStreetMap

Tags: json, openstreetmap, nominatim

In the search page, users can search for places. When they click on the address, a new webpage will display the address details. However the new webpage displays only: "Place details not found in Nominatim database". What should I fix in my code ?

search page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Search</h1>
    <input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search for a place">
    <button id="searchButton">Search</button>
    <div id="placeDetails"></div>

  <script src="scripttest.js"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

javascritp for search page

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const searchButton = document.getElementById("searchButton");
    searchButton.addEventListener("click", searchPlace);
});

function searchPlace() {
    const searchInput = document.getElementById("searchInput");
    const placeName = searchInput.value;
    getPlaceDetails(placeName);
}

function getPlaceDetails(placeName) {
    // Make a request to Nominatim's API to fetch place details
    fetch(`https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&q=${placeName}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                displayPlaceResults(data);
            } else {
                displayErrorMessage("Place not found.");
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error("Error fetching place details:", error);
            displayErrorMessage("An error occurred while fetching place details.");
        });
}

function displayPlaceResults(results) {
    const placeDetails = document.getElementById("placeDetails");
    placeDetails.innerHTML = "";
    
    if (results.length === 1) {
        displayPlaceDetails(results[0]);
    } else if (results.length > 1) {
        const resultList = document.createElement("ul");
        results.forEach(place => {
            const item = document.createElement("li");
            const link = document.createElement("a");
            link.href = `details.html?place_id=${place.place_id}`;
            link.textContent = place.display_name;
            item.appendChild(link);
            resultList.appendChild(item);
        });
        placeDetails.appendChild(resultList);
    } else {
        placeDetails.innerHTML = `<p>No results found.</p>`;
    }
}


function displayPlaceDetails(placeId) {
    // Make a request to Nominatim's API to fetch place details by place_id
    fetch(`https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details?format=json&place_id=${placeId}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            displaySelectedPlaceDetails(data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error("Error fetching place details:", error);
            displayErrorMessage("An error occurred while fetching place details.");
        });
}

function displaySelectedPlaceDetails(place) {
    const placeDetails = document.getElementById("placeDetails");
    placeDetails.innerHTML = `
        <h2>${place.display_name}</h2>
        <p>Street: ${place.address.road || 'N/A'}</p>
        <p>Building Number: ${place.address.house_number || 'N/A'}</p>
    `;
}

function displayErrorMessage(message) {
    const placeDetails = document.getElementById("placeDetails");
    placeDetails.innerHTML = `<p>${message}</p>`;
}
```

new page with place details

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Details</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Place Details</h1>
    <div id="placeDetails"></div>
    
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            const placeId = getPlaceIdFromUrl();
            if (placeId) {
                getPlaceDetails(placeId);
            }
        });

        function getPlaceIdFromUrl() {
            const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
            const placeId = urlParams.get("place_id");
            console.log("Extracted place_id: ", placeId);
            return placeId;
        }

        function getPlaceDetails(placeId) {
            fetch(`https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details?format=json&place_id=${placeId}`)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    return response.json();
                } else {
                    throw new Error(`Error fetching place details: HTTP status ${response.status}`);
                }
            })
            .then(data => {
                if (data.address) {
                    displaySelectedPlaceDetails(data);
                } else {
                    displayErrorMessage("Place details not found in Nominatim database.");
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error("Error fetching place details:", error);
                displayErrorMessage("An error occurred while fetching place details.");
            });
            
        }



        function displaySelectedPlaceDetails(place) {
            const placeDetails = document.getElementById("placeDetails");
            const address = place.addresstags || {};

            const street = address.road || 'N/A';
            const buildingNumber = address.house_number || 'N/A';

            placeDetails.innerHTML = `
                <h2>${place.names.name}</h2>
                <p>Street: ${street}</p>
                <p>Building Number: ${buildingNumber}</p>
            `;
        }




        function displayErrorMessage(message) {
            const placeDetails = document.getElementById("placeDetails");
            placeDetails.innerHTML = `<p>${message}</p>`;
        }
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I have checked if the "place_id" retrieved from API is correct and it seems to be ok. However the address details doesn't come up in my web page